# C++/ATL Project + Arduino(Serial Port) + DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino, atl

I'm newbie at C++, I want to make a School Project using a program which its functionality can be extended through COM components, so I'm supposed to make an ATL Project on Visual Studio 2010 and somehow I need to read information from an Arduino connected to a PC. Excuse my ignorance, Could you suggest me how can I do that? please. Also, I would like to know if I can use a serial port wrapper like CSerialPort and everything could be inside a DLL component.